# How is Guice IoC?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, guice

I've been using Spring in other projects but I want to give Guice a try. So I look up for tutorials and examples and I found this:

```
public interface MyService {
   void serviceOperation1();
   void serviceOperation2();
   void serviceOperation3();
}

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
   @Inject
   public MyServiceImpl() {
   }
   public void serviceOperation1() {
      // ...
   }
   public void serviceOperation2() {
      // ...
   }
   public void serviceOperation3() {
      // ...
   }
}

public class MyServiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(MyService.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    }
}
```

I'm developing my projects in modules like this:
[image: simple project diagram]

I don't want any cycle dependencies.

where can I put `MyServiceModule` class so I don't have a dependency from `core` to `data`?

Putting `MyServiceModule`in the `core` or putting it in the `data` its going to make me import the `MyServiceImpl` or `MyServiceModule` (respectively) making `core` dependent of the `data` module, and `data` dependent of `core`???

Am I missing some important concepts? In Spring I would use the context to get the implementation of `MyService`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your problem? Do you have circle dependency?

Comment: @nachokk yes, I want to avoid it. The `core` has to make calls to the `data` module to persist the data to the database. That means, to call `MyService.create(user)` I've to make this: `Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyServiceModule());` in the `core` and I don't want `core` depending on any "external" module. Do I have to pass the `Injector` by a setter or something? Who is the responsible to build the object graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you split things up.  If you put it all in one place, they'll have one set of dependencies.

Remember, MyServiceModule WILL and must depend on MyServiceImpl, because it is that which configures the impl.  It is like the context xml file, only in java.  Typically one would structure something like this:

```
my/app/core/buildfile (pom.xml or build.xml or whatever)
my/app/core/MyService.java

my/app/service/impl/buildfile (pom.xml or build.xml or whatever)
my/app/service/impl/MyServiceImpl.java
my/app/service/impl/MyServiceImplModule.java

my/app/web/buildfile (pom.xml or build.xml or whatever)
my/app/web/WebServerMain.java

and 

// Uses install() in its configure() method to include
// my/app/service/impl/MyServiceImplModule
my/app/web/ApplicationModule.java
```

At a project level, then, exactly as you have said it:

```
my/app/web/buildfile -> my/app/core/buildfile
my/app/service/impl/buildfile -> my/app/core/buildfile
```

but of course the web package needs to know about implementations in the final configuration

```
my/app/web/buildfile -> my/app/impl/buildfile
```

No dependency cycles. And at a file level, you get these dependencies (described by type just for clarity - java doesn't care, naturally)

```
WebServerMain -- uses --> MyService
WebServerMain -- uses --> ApplicationModule // passes it to Guice to get an Injector
ApplicationModule -- installs --> MyServiceImplModule
MyServiceImplModule -- declares --> MyService // to use as a key
MyServiceImplModule -- binds --> MyServiceImpl // as implementation of MyService
MyServiceImpl -- inherits from --> MyService
```

Here again, no cycles.  ApplicationModule includes the service module (just for decomposition - you could just add that module in Guice.create(new MyServiceImplModule()) directly.  The point is that the module for the impl needs to be separated rom the

Comment: thx, I'm re-reading the post to have a better understanding. Its not an easy concept to grasp. Nevertheless, I think that part of your answer got trunkated and it looks like it is important.